# Lua gsub replace "%%" with "%"

Tags: lua

I'm trying to use lua's string:gsub function to turn "%%p" into "%p"

For example, my code looks like
local a = "Hello%%pWorld"
a = a:gsub("%%","%")
print(a)
I get the error: "invalid use of '%' in replacement string"

I tried a:gsub("%%","%%") but that just gives me "Hello%%pWorld" again

I can get what I want using a:find("%%") and then using a:sub to join it back together, without the single "%", but that seems rather convoluted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%%` matches a single `%`, because `%` is the escape char in Lua patterns.

Try `a = a:gsub("%%%%","%%")`.

Comment: Tried
local a = "Hello%%pWorld"
a:gsub("%%%%","%%")
print(a)

Get output > Hello%%pWorld

Comment: @James, you need to do `a = a:gsub("%%%%","%%")` as in your question.

Comment: Oops, that was embarassing! Thank you very much. This works perfectly

Comment: `%%%%` is Lua's variant of [LTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome) :-)

Comment: @lhf - Yes, `a:gsub("%%%%","%%")` is better than `a:gsub("\\\\\\\\","\\\\")`.  But there exist even more easy readable version: `a:gsub("%%{2}","%%")` which is unfortunately not implemented in Lua. ;-)